# How can I get a component's position on screen (screen coordinates)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I want to show a window at a position relative to a given component.

Is there a way to determine a component's screen coordinates?

So I can then use those to set the window's position:

```
window.setPosition(x, y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can not get position of any `Component` at server side, that information resides client side. Ultimately you can not achieve this directly in `vaadin`. But  you can create an [extension](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.extension.html) of the `Component` and extend your server side component in it and from the `Connector` you can provide the position of vaadin client side widget to the extension reside at Server side. You can manage position of component in `State`.This may sound difficult but you can easily accomplish this. You can follow Book of vaadin as usual for this.

Comment: I ended up copying the source of the mouse events addon and modifying it to pass the widget's absolute x/y and width/height to the mouse over/out handlers.